# Is the "wall of solitude" a reference to Pink Floyd's "The Wall"?

Tags: russian-language, allusions, andrey-kurkov, death-and-the-penguin

*Death and the Penguin* contains the following quote:

> He thought suddenly of Nina and her saying that they had been seeing Sergey off at the station. So he had, after all, gone to Moscow, without so much as a goodbye. It was another brick in Viktor's wall of solitude.

Is this a reference to Pink Floyd's *The Wall*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The metaphorical use of “another brick in the wall” to mean “a small component of a much larger structure, system, or process” (*OED*) was popularized by the Pink Floyd song, but long predates it. The *OED*’s first couple of citations are:

> 1867   *Sharpe’s London Mag.* Feb. 60/1   It was only another brick in the wall of separation.
> 1945   *Corona (Calif.) Daily Independent* 2 Mar. 4/2   Branding the..bills as ‘merely another brick in the wall of totalitarianism being built in America’, the group..denounced the compulsory features of the proposals.

The equivalent phrase “but a brick in the wall” has a similar antiquity:

> 1878   G. B. Malleson [*History of the Indian Mutiny 1857–1858* I.289](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.81849/page/n325/mode/2up)   It was but a brick in the wall of Indian administration.
> 1914   A. S. Hobart [*Transplanted Truths: Or, Expositions of Great Texts in Ephesians* 46](https://archive.org/details/transplantedtru00hobagoog/page/n58/mode/2up)   He may be but a brick in the wall of society
> 1918   [*The Elevator Constructor* XV.9 5](https://archive.org/details/elevatorconstru00consgoog/page/n214/mode/2up)   A man, they say, is but a brick in the wall of an edifice

So the use of the phrase is not, by itself, evidence that a reference to the song is intended.